# Does there exist a continuous surjective map $\mathbb R \to \ell^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Does there exist a continuous surjective map $\mathbb R \to \ell^2$?

I am not even sure how to construct a general function that satisfies this, let alone a continuous one. Could I have a hint please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Assume that such continuous surjection $f$ exists then
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f([-n,n])=l^2.$$
Now each $f([-n,n])$ is compact and $l^2$ is complete. Find a contradiction by using the [Baire Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

P.S. Note that $l^2\subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and the set of real sequences $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ has the same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. This implies that there is a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $l^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. So there exists an open ball in $f([-k,k])$ for some $k$. I shall think about how to obtain a contradiction from this.